# Make Box Around Page Red

Tags: fbox

I have used …

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\fancypage{}{\fbox}
```

… to put a box around my text on every page including header and footer. It looks how I want it, except for the color. How do I make it red instead of black? I am using `LuaLaTeX` to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used: `\fancypage{}{\fcolorbox{red}{white}}`